# The kernel 'base (Python 3.9.7)' died when using PyQt5

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using Jupyter Notebook on Vscode and I'm new to PyQt5. When I run these lines of code, I got this Error message

[image]

I tried restarting the kernel and it only works once each time it but doesn't display the widget fully either. Here's a screenshot of the output

[image]

PS, I am using Anaconda 3 and Python 3 on Windows 10 16 GB RAM 64 bit

And here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit, QTableWidget, QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 

class welcomescreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(welcomescreen,self).__init__()
        loadUi("welcome.ui", self)



# main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

if app is None:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
acceuil=welcomescreen() #object from the class above
widget=QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(acceuil)
widget.setFixedHeight(850)
widget.setFixedWidth(1200)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Comment: First of all, just ignore that "Code first with Hala" tutorial, as it provides a huge amount of *terrible* suggestions and bad practices. Then: 1. if you want to keep jupyter/ipython active when the program quits, you shall *not* use `sys.exit()`; 2. if the problem happens just after running that code, then there's probably a problem in the class (maybe the wrong path of the ui file, ensure that the name is *actually* correct and you're running from the same directory of that file, or just use the full path); 3. remove that `try/except` block, as it prevents seeing the traceback of the error->

Comment: -> (and that's just one of the issues that tutorial irresponsibly ignores); 4. do *not* add a QDialog to a QStackedWidget, use QWidget instead; 5. the `if app is None` after `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` doesn't make any sense: it should be `app = QApplication.instance()`; 6. classes should have Capitalized Names; 7. try to use more consistent imports: importing the whole QtWidgets module and then separate classes is just confusing and pointless.